# How close to division by zero can I get?

Tags: c++, c

I want to avoid dividing by zero so I have an `if` statement:

```
float number;
//........
if (number > 0.000000000000001) 
  number = 1/number;
```

How small of a value can I safely use in place of `0.000000000000001`?

Comment: `number != 0` ?

Comment: @Nbr44 You should generally compare `float/doubles` against integers due to rounding errors.

Comment: What are you trying to avoid? You won't get an exception for dividing by zero, just `Inf`.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the division by zero? In many platforms that will yield a `Inf`, which is a perfectly valid value and probably what you will get if you divide by a small enough number anyways.

Comment: You're looking for the smallest double value: DBL_MIN

Comment: @anorton `DBL_MIN` is not the smallest nonzero positive double. It is the smallest positive normalized double. The smallest nonzero positive double can be obtained as `DBL_MIN * DBL_EPSILON` or `nextafter(0, 1)`

Comment: @PascalCuoq Hmm... ok.  I'm out of my element here... :)

Comment: anorton suggestion makes more sense to me

Comment: @bash.d In this case, where it is exactly about avoiding the `0`, it would be ok. However, the usable range of `double`s extends more towards +Inf that to 0: the lowest number representable seems to be 4.94065645841e-324, but its inverse is Inf. 1.11253692925e-308 is the lowest number having a non-infinite inverse (8.98846567431e+307).

Comment: Okay, people, still it shouldn't become a habit.

Comment: @glglgl: 1.11253692925e-308 is not the lowest number having a finite inverse. 5.5626846462680083984e-309 is lower, and `1 / 5.5626846462680083984e-309` produces 1.7976931348623143111e+308.

Comment: The `else` case is suspiciously absent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number in the `if` condition depends on what you want to do with the result.  In IEEE 754, which is used by (almost?) all C implementations, dividing by 0 is OK: you get positive or negative infinity.

If your goal is to avoid +/- Infinity, then the number in the `if` condition will depend upon the numerator.  When the numerator is 1, you can use `DBL_MIN` or `FLT_MIN` from `math.h`.

If your goal is to avoid huge numbers after the division, you can do the division and then check if `fabs(number)` is bigger than certain value after the division, and then take whatever action as needed.

There is no single correct answer to your question.

Comment: `DBL_MIN` is the wrong limit for whether `1/number` produces infinity. E.g., `1 / (.75 * DBL_MIN)` produces about 5.99231e307, not infinity.

Comment: @EricPostpischil you're right.  I forgot about denormal numbers while answering.  Thanks!

Comment: @EricPostpischil seems like the correct answer is `nextafter(1.0/DBL_MAX, 1)` in this case.

Answer (score 9):

Just use:

```
if(number > 0)
    number = 1/number;
```

Note the difference between `>` and `>=`. If `number > 0`, then it definitely is not `0`.

If number can be negative you can also use:

```
if(number != 0)
    number = 1/number;
```

Note that, as others have mentioned in the comments, checking that `number` is not `0` will not prevent your result from being `Inf` or `-Inf`.

Comment: let's say my number could be negative  should compare it abs(number) !=0 wouldn't work for let's 0.35 *10^35

Comment: @Engine That's because `abs` returns an int not a float/double in `C`. There is no need to use `abs` there. `0.35*10^35` is not equal to `0`. Here's proof: http://ideone.com/18Yd8X

Comment: @Engine: What do you think the problem is .35*10^35 would be? Or .35*10^-35, if that is what you meant? If a number is not zero, then dividing by it does not produce division by zero. So this problem you are trying to solve, avoiding dividing by zero, is entirely solved by testing whether the divisor is zero.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Hmm well I'm not sure what else could be the problem as `0.35e35` definitely doesn't compare as equal to `0`. I'm quite certain that in `C` abs only works with `int` and in `C++` it works with `double`s. See here: http://ideone.com/by1uFr

Answer (score 3):

You can simply check:

```
if (number > 0)
```

I can't understand why you need the lower limit.

Comment: Because if the number is close to 0, the result can still be INF. Trivially, in the case of `DBL_MAX/0.5`, 0.5 is already too close.

Answer (score 3):

For numeric type T std::numeric_limits gives you anything you need. For example you could do this to make sure that anything above min_invertible has finite reciprocal:

```
float max_float = std::numeric_limits<float>::max(); 
float min_float = std::numeric_limits<float>::min(); // or denorm_min()
float min_invertible = (max_float*min_float > 1.0f )? min_float : 1.0f/max_float;
```

Comment: I _really_ do like this answer especially for the `max_float*min_float > 1.0f` test.  But might not max_float & min_float be so close to being logarithmic opposites and with various rounding modes that "max_float*min_float" is 1.0 and "1.0f/max_float" is 0.0.  As a candidate alternative, how about `(1.0f/max_float)? 1.0f/max_float : min_float`?  Maybe that suffers a similar edge condition.

Answer (score 3):

You can't decently check up front. `DBL_MAX / 0.5` effectively is a division by zero; the result is the same infinity you'd get from any other division by (almost) zero.

There is a simple solution: just check the result. `std::isinf(result)` will tell you whether the result overflowed, and IEEE754 tells you that division cannot produce infinity in other cases. (Well, except for INF/x,. That's not really producing infinity but merely preserving it.)

Answer (score 1):

Your risk of producing an unhelpful result through overflow or underflow depends on both numerator and denominator.

A safety check which takes that into consideration is:

```
if (den == 0.0 || log2(num) - log2(den) >= log2(FLT_MAX))
    /* expect overflow */ ;
else
    return num / den;
```

but you might want to shave a small amount off `log2(FLT_MAX)` to leave wiggle-room for subsequent arithmetic and round-off.

You can do something similar with `frexp`, which would work for negative values as well:

```
int max;
int n, d;

frexp(FLT_MAX, &max);

frexp(num, &n);
frexp(den, &d);

if (den == 0.0 || n - d > max)
    /* might overflow */ ;
else
    return num / den;
```

This avoids the work of computing the logarithm, which might be more efficient if the compiler can find a suitable way of doing it, but it's not as accurate.

Answer (score 0):

With IEEE 32-bit floats, the smallest possible value greater than 0 is 2^-149.

If you're using IEEE 64-bit, the smallest possible value is 2^-1074.

That said, (x > 0) is probably the better test.

Comment: For IEEE 754 double-precision, the smallest value is 2^-1074. It is smaller than 2^-1022 for the same reason that 2^-149, the smallest strictly positive single-precision value, is smaller than 2^-126.